# How to add safeStringify() to JSON in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, stringify

I want to have `safeStringify` for `json` objects.
for this purpose, I want to add it to `interface JSON` in `Typescript` (`lib.d.ts`)

```
interface JSON {
    safeStringify(value: any): string; // Right way ? - How to write the body ?
}
```

[image: safeStringify]

1. Is this a right way for extending `JSON interface` or not? (browser and node)
2. If yes, How can I add the functionality (method body)? the interfaces do not accept a body.

I want to work the code globally without any effort just as JSON member.

[image: safeStringify]

**UPDATE:**

so the final result/answer is:

[image: safeStringify]

Comment: Simple as `JSON.safeStringify = o => JSON.stringify(o); // put your implementation`

Comment: @AlekseyL. please see my post again Can you explain more? or Write the correct code as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've defined the interface, but not the implementation:

```
interface JSON {
    safeStringify(value: any): string;
}

JSON.safeStringify = function(value: any): string {
    ... your implementation
}
```

You also need to ensure you include safeStringify.ts in your build.

Unless of course safeStringify comes from some lib, in which case, just ensure you import the lib correctly.

Comment: I should add `import './safeStringify';`

Comment: @HF_67 Yes, but I'm not sure if that works without an export. I still don't fully understand the semantics of JavaScript's import/export. All still seems a bit immature and thrown together IMO.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion for how to export it? How to export `JSON.safeStringify` ?

Comment: @HF_67  `default export JSON.safeStringify... etc` might be what you’re after